# 自作フォントをxcodeでデータ化できますか

Tags: macos, font

Xcodeというソフトで自分で作製したフォント（文字）をOpenTypefontなどの形式でデータ化し、wordなどで表示したいのですが出来ますでしょうか？

またはそれが出来なくてもiosのアプリとしてキーボードをタッピングすると画面に自作のフォントを表示することができますでしょうか？

Xcodeの中ではObjectiveCやC等の言語が選べますが、今回のような事が実現可能であればどの言語を選べば良いでしょうか？

できないのであれば他の（できればmacパソコンでできる）ふさわしい言語を教えて下さると有難く思っております。

簡単で構いませんので宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 疑問が解決した際は質問文に書くのではなく、回答の承認をお願いします。 http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1735/8000

Answer (score 2):

Xcodeは、ソフトウェアを開発する環境ですから、フォントを作成する（あなたのいう「フォントをデータにする」）アプリケーションを開発することは可能です。しかし、Xcodeは、フォントを作成するアプリケーション自身ではありません。
さっとネット検索すると、フォントを作成するアプリケーションで見つかるのは、下のようなものです。

[OTEdit for Mac](http://opentype.jp/oteditmac.htm)

フォントに関する基礎知識について説明が必要なようなので、すこしフォントの概要を説明しますが、OpenTypeフォントと、TrueTypeフォントは、Windows、Mac、iOS（iPhone/iPad）で、共通してインストールできます（Androidは知りません。たぶんできると思いますが、必要であるならそれはあなたがご自分でお調べください。）。「自分で作製したフォント」というのが、もしTrueTypeフォントであるなら、あえてOpenTypeに作り替える必要はありません。そのままでどのデバイスにもインストール可能です。

※あなたがご自身の質問に追加を行った場合、可能であれば、追加分に即した説明の増補を行う用意があります。

Answer (score 1):

私は普段Android専門で、iOSは最近やり始めたばかりですが・・・ご質問の、
１．Xcodeというソフトで自分で作製したフォント（文字）をOpenTypefontなどの形式でデータ化し、wordなどで表示したいのですが出来ますでしょうか？

２．またはそれが出来なくてもiosのアプリとしてキーボードをタッピングすると画面に自作のフォントを表示することができますでしょうか？

について、それぞれやり方が全く異なるので、共通の方法では無理です。恐らく、最終目標が質問２．だと予想して説明いたします。

まず、１．についてはXcodeで自作することも可能だとは思いますが、それなりに難しいと思われますので、何らかの市販ソフトを使うべきだと思います。

市販のフォント作成ソフトを用いてフォントファイルを作成し、それをmac等、使用しているパソコンにインストールすることで、wordなどで表示可能です。インストールするには、フォントファイルをダブルクリックするとフォント管理用ソフトが立ち上がると思いますので、その指示通りやれば大丈夫です（最近のものであれば、win、mac共にダブルクリックでインストール可能です）。
試しにインストールしてみるのであれば、IPAが作成したIPAフォントをインストールしてみるのが良いと思います。ただし、そのままアプリに組み込んで配布するのはNGですから、ライセンスをよく確認して下さい。
http://ipafont.ipa.go.jp/index.html
インストールが完了後wordを起動すると、wordのフォント一覧の部分にインストールしたフォントが追加されます。

２．は、作成済みのフォントファイルをiOSアプリの作成過程でアプリに組み込むことで実現します。これは、Androidアプリなどでも同様で、まずフォントファイルが無いと無理です。なので、まず１．が出来ない状態では実現出来ません。裏ワザとしては、文字をイラストレータ等で画像として作成し、文字では無く画像を表示するという方法も無くはないですが、メモリも多く消費しますし、あまり良い方法ではありません。

ということで、２．を最短で実現するには、市販のフォント作成ソフトでフォントファイルを作成し、それをiOSアプリの作成過程で組み込むという形になると思います。